# What is wrong with this expression and the match operator?

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to retrieve the value of a column from a $objMatch object, to determine if a string matches this model XXXXX or XXXXX-YYY or XXXXX-YYY-ZZZ using the `-match` operator.  The script I made always returns a false.

```
> The Jobstream column of $NewExtract contains data for example ACGN100Q or ACGN-100Q-000T that is not present in $oldElementsCsv. I also know that the data in the Jobstream column of $NewExtract and the Name column of $oldElementsCsv may or may not match. So, if the data don't match between these two columns, and the value of the Jobstream column doesn't contain a dash or an underscore for example ACGN100Q I assign to the column Type = "TechnologyService", in all other cases I assign to the column Type = "TechnologyInteraction", then I will be able to generate a new file newElements.csv

$oldElementsCsv = Import-Csv .\elements.csv -Delimiter ','
$NewExtract2 = Import-Csv .\NewExtract.csv -Delimiter ','
#Output progress:
$output = @()
ForEach ($row in $NewExtract2) {

    $objMatch = $oldElementsCsv | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $row."Jobstream" } 
    $pattern='^(.*)-'
                         $pattern2='^(.*)_'
                        if($objMatch."Name"  -notmatch $pattern){
                
                                $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); Type="TechnologyInteraction"; Name= $row."Jobstream"; Documentation= $row."Job Description"}   
                                 Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
                                 Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"
                        }  elseif($objMatch."Name"  -match $pattern2) {
                                
                                $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); Type="TechnologyInteraction"; Name= $row.Jobstream; Documentation= $row."Job Description"} 
                               # Write-Warning "New Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
                                #Write-Warning "New Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"
                                Write-Host "ifelse condition met"
                                
                        }else{

                          $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); Type="TechnologyService"; Name= $row.Jobstream; Documentation= $row."Job Description"} 
                              Write-Host "else condition met"
                               # Write-Warning "New Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
                               # Write-Warning "New Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"

                        }
}
$output | Select-Object "ID", "Type", "Name", "Documentation" | Export-Csv .\newElements.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

`elements.csv`:

```
ID,"Type","Name","Documentation"        
79570056-ab4f-6969-8c58-a5bd5847a736,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO900Q","RMN2 - xACTO1R"                    
79570056-ab4f-6969-8c58-a5bd5847a737,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO901H","RMN1 - xACTO1R"                    
79570056-ab4f-6969-8c58-a5bd5847a738,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO902H","RMNF - xACTO1R"                    
79570056-ab4f-6969-8c58-a5bd5847a739,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO982Q","RMN1 - xACTO1R"                    
79570056-ab4f-6969-8c58-a5bd5847a740,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO984H","RMN2 - xACTO1R"                    
b57a5fff-9dd2-4ce1-9141-04c042f49018,"TechnologyService","ACTO210Q-010M","Lancement traitement"                 
b57a5fff-9dd2-4ce1-9141-04c042f49021,"TechnologyService","ACTO300Q-040-000M","Begin Of JobStream"
```

`NewExtract.csv`:

```
Jobstream,"Jobstream Description","Op num","Job","Script or expected file(s)","Server","user","location","Job Description"
ACGN100Q,"f_ref12 to SalesForce","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream"
ACGN-100Q-000T,"f_ref12 to SalesForce","40","PACGN0AC","PACGN-100Q-000T.KSH","PRATFUDMGTW01","svcudmu","F+ACGN-001","Transfert UDM (xACGN000)"
ACGN-100Q-010T,"f_ref12 to SalesForce","50","PACGN0AD","PACGN-100Q-010T.KSH","CARAA009","SVC_SE_PROD_ACGN01","F+ACGN-002","move fichier REF to work"
ACGN-100Q-020T,"f_ref12 to SalesForce","60","PACGN0AE","PACGN-100Q-020T.KSH","CARAA009","SVC_SE_PROD_ACGN01","F+ACGN-002","w_read_account"
```

I want to generate a file that looks like this:
newElements.csv:

> ID,"Type","Name","Documentation"
> 55cd2d0a-9b10-4cdd-a597-1b6637faada0,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO900Q","Begin Of JobStream"
> 05f34829-dd19-4c4f-99a9-3d5e4d094d34,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO901H","Begin Of JobStream"
> 5719bc7b-b996-446f-9dec-674109fafc82,"TechnologyInteraction","ACTO902H","Begin Of JobStream"
> 9719bc7b-b996-446f-9dec-674109fafc82,"TechnologyService","ACTO902H-005S","Begin Of JobStream"
> Thanks for your help

Comment: Please, add the expected output (`.\newElements.csv`) to the question. (note that I see no matching properties between the sample input files. Which rows should actually match here?)

Comment: `$objMatch` is set to every line of elements.csv matching a `name`, and you're only checking the third match `$objMatch[2]` against your regex? Your regex is only negative, and only checking for one character `-`? Some more context might help understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> The match should be done on $row. "Jobstream" and not on the columns of $objMatch . Thanks to all of you.

```
$oldElementsCsv = Import-Csv .\elements.csv -Delimiter ','
$NewExtract2 = Import-Csv .\NewExtract.csv -Delimiter ','
#Output progress:
$output = @()
ForEach ($row in $NewExtract2) {

    $objMatch = $oldElementsCsv | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $row."Jobstream" } 
    $pattern='^(.*)-'
                         $pattern2='^(.*)_'
                        if($row."Jobstream"   -notmatch $pattern){
                
                                $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); Type="TechnologyInteraction"; Name= $row."Jobstream"; Documentation= $row."Job Description"}   
                                 Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
                                 Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"
                        }  elseif($row."Jobstream"   -match $pattern2) {
                                
                                $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); Type="TechnologyInteraction"; Name= $row.Jobstream; Documentation= $row."Job Description"} 
                               # Write-Warning "New Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
                                #Write-Warning "New Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"
                                Write-Host "ifelse condition met"
                                
                        }else{

                          $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); Type="TechnologyService"; Name= $row.Jobstream; Documentation= $row."Job Description"} 
                              Write-Host "else condition met"
                               # Write-Warning "New Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
                               # Write-Warning "New Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"

                        }
}
$output | Select-Object -Property ID,Type,Name,Documentation| Export-Csv .\newElements.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```